# Configure oracle in debian testing

Tags: debian, oracle, oracle10g

I have installed oracle10 in debian, in the web ui i can use the database, but this doesn't work with sqlplus, where i can configure this?

updated:

when i run sqlplus in command line, ask me for login and password, i digit the same of web interface and i get this error:

ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

Comment: Care to share any errors you see?

Comment: Are you sure your shell environment is correct (see my answer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually indicates ORACLE_SID is incorrectly or not set.

Make sure your environment variables ORACLE_HOME (directory where you installed Oracle) and ORACLE_SID (database instance) are defined and exported, e.g.:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/product/10.2.0/DB; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=your_DB; export ORACLE_SID     (note that case is significant on *nix instance names)
sqlplus user/pw
```

EDIT:

Can you connect through a listener? In other words, assuming your instance is defined in your tnsnames.ora file, then does the following allow you to connect:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect user@your_DB
```

Comment: what is the ORACLE_SID default? XE?

Comment: I'm not sure what the DB name limitations are on the instance, but whatever the name of the instance, your environment needs to have ORACLE_SID set to it and exported.